# Python argparse - help text for long argument name

Tags: python, command-line-arguments, argparse

Python 'argparse' display help text on a new line for a long named argument :

```
**#script.py -h

Select one of the options given


optional arguments:
  -h, --help            show this help message and exit
  -bs , --business_service 
                        choose the service     << New line
  -so , --service_offering 
  -ci , --cmdb_ci       provide configuration item
  -desc , --description 
                        write description     << New line
```

Below is the code I'm using:

```
self.parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(
            description='Select one of the options given',
            epilog=self._get_usage(),
            formatter_class=argparse.RawTextHelpFormatter
            )


        self.parser.add_argument('-bs','--business_service',type=str,help='choose the service',metavar='')
        self.parser.add_argument('-so','--service_offering',type=str,metavar='')
        self.parser.add_argument('-ci','--mdcb_ci',type=str,help='provide configuration item',metavar='')
        self.parser.add_argument('-desc','--description',type=str,help='write description',metavar='')
```

I want the help string to be on the same line of the argument :

```
-bs , --business_service     choose the service     << Same line
```

How can I solve it?

Comment: Probably not without digging fairly deep into the argparse library… If the formatting of the help text is that important for you, [docopt](https://github.com/docopt/docopt) might be the better option for you.

Comment: Shorten the long option name(s) is by far the simplest solution.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `HelpFormatter` class takes a `max_help_position` argument.  The default value is 24, which is what you are seeing in the help.

It can be changed with a new Formatter subclass, or modification to the calling argument.

```
In [23]: parser.formatter_class = 
    lambda prog: argparse.RawTextHelpFormatter(prog, max_help_position=30)
```

Here I'm modifying the `formatter_class` attribute after, but you could instead use this `lambda` line in place of

```
formatter_class=argparse.RawTextHelpFormatter
```

The result is:

```
In [24]: parser.print_help()
usage: ipython3 [-h] [-bs] [-so] [-ci] [-desc]

Select one of the options given

optional arguments:
  -h, --help                 show this help message and exit
  -bs , --business_service   choose the service
  -so , --service_offering 
  -ci , --mdcb_ci            provide configuration item
  -desc , --description      write description
```

Parameters like this were chosen to balance overall width of the display with legibility.  They can be tweaked like this, but it does require some Python programming knowledge.  It's been a while since I did this, so my suggestion might not be the simplest.  But it's generally in the right direction.

Another way of setting it with the `partial` wrapper:

```
In [42]: from functools import partial
In [43]: newformatter=partial(argparse.HelpFormatter, max_help_position=30)
In [44]: parser.formatter_class=newformatter
```